# curl api call to POSTenum data type in flask python framework

Tags: python, curl, flask, sqlalchemy

How do I send enum data type using a POST api call to add data in a postgres table?

What I tried:
the enum data type is defined using sqlalchemy core as:

```
event_type_enum = Enum('Telephonic', 'Online meeting', 'Meeting', "Call",
                  name='event_type_enum')#, create_type=False)
```

The model where this enum is used is defined as (removed the other attributes):

```
events = Table("events", metadata,
               Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
               Column("event_type", event_type_enum),               
               Column("description", String, unique=True))
```

The curl commands tried:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8081/crm/api/v1.0/events_add -d '{"description":"event8", "user_id":2, "event_type":2}' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

and also tried:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8081/crm/api/v1.0/events_add -d '{"description":"event5", "user_id":2, "event_type":"Call"}' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Both these give bad request. Exactly how is enum data sent using curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8081/crm/api/v1.0/events_add -d '{"description":"event5", "user_id":2, "event_type":"Call"}' -H 'Content-type:application/json'

is the correct way. 
Problem is that I had added the 4th value of the enum later, which was not being recognised and giving error.

Also a default value can be set if it is not passed in the curl while defining the enum itself as

```
event_type_enum = Enum('Telephonic', 'Online meeting', 'Meeting', "Call",
name='event_type_enum', default=event_type_enum.enums[2])
```